# setup.py containing an external url: platform specific failure (Windows & Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, pip

This is in my `setup.py`:

```
setup(...,
      install_requires=[
           'fons @ git+https://github.com/binares/fons.git',
       ],
)
```

Installing the package on Windows (pip 19.3.1, python 3.6.5) works just fine, but on Ubuntu 18.04 (pip 9.0.1, python 3.6.9) I get :

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not found for url:
>   https://pypi.org/simple/fons

(I used commands: `pip install wsclient-0.1.0.tar.gz` and `pip3 install wsclient-0.1.0.tar.gz`)

How to make it work on both platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies

> Warning: Dependency links support has been dropped by pip starting with version 19.0 (released 2019-01-22).

The syntax

```
'fons @ git+https://github.com/binares/fons.git'
```

is from [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references) and is supported by [`pip` 19.1+](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers).

Upgrade `pip` at Ubuntu.